# "PlayOnLinux is not supposed to be run as root. Sorry"

Tags: sudo, root, playonlinux

This is the exact message I get in terminal when running `sudo playonlinux`

Any help?

```
dps@dps-ubuntu:~$ sudo playonlinux
Looking for python... 2.7.15rc1 - wxversion(s): 3.0-gtk3
selected
1
PlayOnLinux is not supposed to be run as root. Sorry
Gtk-Message: 17:37:49.376: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `sudo` to run PlayOnLinux. Running PlayOnLinux as root can give Windows programs running in PlayOnLinux root privileges, and expose your operating system to being hacked by the same Windows malware that infects these Windows programs when they run in Windows.

Comment: im going to go ahead and mark this as the answer. bad mistake on my part, thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem as the OP on a pc that only has the root user. The marked answer is philosophical, and the downvoted answer by YanValente still works but it might help others to explain a different way.

In the first file, usr/share/games/playonlinux/lib/sources it's clear where to change the 0 to a 10

In the second file, usr/share/games/playonlinux/python/mainwindow.py there is a line with two 0s in it which should both be changed
But there is a third 0 in the line just below which should be left alone

Answer (score -2):

I did this and solve the problem
go to directory usr/share/games/playonlinux/lib
edit the file sources
change 0 to 10 in the condition ~if~
after, go to directory # usr/share/games/playonlinux/python
edit the file mainwindow.py
search for Root uid check
change the two values of 0 to 10
save and open the playonlinux

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea - removing a security feature.